# Converting to a timestamp Deprecation Error using Moment.js

Tags: angular, momentjs

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Moment.js

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- Take a string value from the material date picker
- Convert it to a time stamp

**My Issue**

- I successfully get the date selected from the material date picker
- This returns a string of 25/12/2017
- On a button hit, I call a test function where I try to convert it to a time stamp. I successfully do this, but I receive an error in the console:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
>   Error

**Question**

- How do I avoid this error?

**My HTML**

```html
<input #mdDatepicker mdInput [mdDatepicker]="picker" (focus)="picker.open()" required />
<label class="vs__input__label">  Date </label>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

**My Test Function**

I've added some comments in the code that show what is printed to the console.

```js
testingDate(value){

    console.log('value = ' + value)
    // value = 11/9/2017

    var newValue = moment(value).format();
    console.log('new value = ' + newValue)
    // new value = 2017-11-09T00:00:00+00:00

    var timestamp = moment(newValue).unix();

    console.log('new date = ' + timestamp);
    // new  date = 1510185600

}
```

Any help with this would be amazing and appreciated!

Comment: I fear that `value` and `newValue` are not JavaScript Dates, but they are strings in a format that is not ISO 8601 compliant. You have to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC - Are you able to provide an answer of where that part would actually go please? I've also updated my question to highlight the value I'm getting back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your value is like `25/12/2017`, you can use `moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY')`.

See  [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) docs.

Your code could be like the following:

```js
testingDate(value){
  var m = moment(value, 'DD/M/YYYY');
  var newValue = m.format();
  var timestamp = m.unix();

  //var newProjectDate = value().unix();
  console.log('new project date = ' + timestamp);
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you! - That get's rid of the error. I hope you don't mind me asking. This prints to the console nicely. However, selecting anything in the same month outputs the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC!